# c99 read digits into vector until ENTER detected

Tags: c99

I've been trying to write a function that could read a series of digits and keep storing them in an vector until the Enter key is pressed.

So, for example, if the user typed `001342` and then Enter, I'd want the vector `v[]` to be:

```
v[0]=0;
v[1]=0;
v[2]=1;
v[3]=3;
v[4]=4;
v[5]=2;
```

So my idea was to use something like this:

```
char v[100];
int t=0,i=0;
printf("Insert a number (max 100 digits): ");
while (t==0) {
    v[i]=getchar();
    i=i+1;
    printf("%c",v[i]);
    if (v[i]=='\n') {
        t=1;
        }
    }
```

It seems it doesn't recognize when I press Enter and just keeps reading more values. Not only that, but if add:

```
printf("%c",v[i]);
```

inside the "while" to try to see what's being stored into the vector, the values are complete gibberish.

Any suggestions?

This is all the relevant code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int SomaAlgarismos();
int Dia_Seguinte();
int testbis();
int capicua();
int capicua2();

    int main() {
    int c;
    printf("Escolha uma opção:\n");
    printf("[1]F2 Ex13 (soma algarismos)\n");
    printf("[2]F2 Ex14 (dia seguinte)\n");
    printf("[3]F2 Ex12 (capicua)\n");
    printf("[4]--Template--\n");
    printf("[5]Sair\n");
    scanf("%d",&c);
    switch (c) {
        case (3):
            capicua2();
            printf("\n");
            main();
            break;

// other options here

        default:
            printf("Opção Inválida\n");
        break;  }   }


int capicua2()  {

char v[5000];
int t=0,i=0;
printf("Introduza um número: ");
while (t==0) {
    v[i]=getchar();
    i=i+1;
    printf("%c",v[i]);
    if (v[i]=='\n') {
        t=1;
    }
}
return 0;   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using fgets() to read a whole string of digits at once. 
Something like this...

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i;
    char v[100];
    int len = sizeof v / sizeof v[0];

    fgets(&v[0], len, stdin);
    i = 0;
    while (v[i] != 0 && v[i] != '\n') {
        printf("v[%d] = %c\n", i, v[i]);
        ++i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sadly it ends with the same problem, just skips the reading and/or the values just become random. ive edited the first post to show in more detail my problem

Comment: i think the problem is that, on my main(), the switch i use as a "menu" sends values to the keyboard that later get read on the getchar or the fgets. but fflush didnt solve it either, so, im kinda stuck